# MongoDb.Driver throws exception when I remove entity class property

Tags: c#, mongodb, migration

I'm new to MongoDb and using a simple class and inserted two records with this structure into a database.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{{ Id: {Id}, Name: {Name}  }}";
    }
}
```

I can read them by this code and everything is fine.

```
var client = new MongoClient();
var db = client.GetDatabase("test-update");
var people = db.GetCollection<Person>("people").Find(p => true).ToList();

foreach (var person in people)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person.ToString());
}
```

The result is:

```
{ Id: 1, Name: person 1  }
{ Id: 2, Name: person 2  }
```

---

Now if I remove the Property1 from my Person class, and run the read code again, I'll run into this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Element 'Property1' does not match any field or property of class Person.
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeClass(BsonDeserializationContext context)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.CursorBatchDeserializationHelper.DeserializeBatch[TDocument](RawBsonArray batch, IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSet
tings)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindCommandOperation`1.CreateCursorBatch(BsonDocument result)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindCommandOperation`1.ExecuteCommand(IReadBinding binding, ServerDescription serverDescription, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindCommandOperation`1.Execute(IReadBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindOperation`1.Execute(IReadBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteReadOperation[TResult](IReadBinding binding, IReadOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteReadOperation[TResult](IReadOperation`1 operation, ReadPreference readPreference, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteReadOperation[TResult](IReadOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindSync[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.FindFluent`2.ToCursor(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.ToList[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ConsoleApplication.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\choro\Desktop\mongo-update\Program.cs:line 12
```

This is just a test project and these kind of changes in metadata would be happened all the time in real projects. How do I manage these changes to avoid errors.

In EF and SQL Server I always used Automatic Migrations and didn't have to think about the metadata changes. But I don't know what to do in case of MongoDb.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a little browsing in MongoDb documentation, found an attribute '[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]' that worked for me.

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public string Property1 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{{ Id: {Id}, Name: {Name}  }}";
    }
}
```

The official explanation is this:

> When a BSON document is deserialized, the name of each element is used
>   to look up a matching member in the class map. Normally, if no
>   matching member is found, an exception will be thrown. If you want to
>   ignore extra elements during deserialization, use a
>   BsonIgnoreExtraElementsAttribute

Comment: This works, but it isn't an ideal answer. The data doesn't go away, it just stays in Mongo hidden from your application. By having Mongo throw an exception, it helps catch mistakes. If you rename a field from "LastName" to "Surname" in C# but not Mongo, you will lose the data in that field. With this attribute you wouldn't notice and could introduce bugs into your system. I would recommend writing a script to keep your data matching your model if possible.

Answer (score 0):

By removing a property from your model, your model and database documents isn't in sync, cause mongo cannot deserialize documents to your model. you should remove Property1 from mongo documents too.

Comment: You're right. My point is there's got to be an automatic way to do that for me. I shouldn't be worried about syncing classes and databases together.